# CIVIL 3D, overlapped cross section while Corridor is being processed

Tags: autocad

I would like to ask some questions about how to modify or fix the overlapped cross section created in the process of Corridor.

Down there is a picture depicting what happened.

Little advice would be a big helping hand for me.

Thanks.

[image]